# Spring Integration Stateful TCP Connection

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I'm trying to create a TCP client with **org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory**. When Factory createing TCP connection I'll need send some data to server, like as authorization. Server sent some data in response(e.g. **salt**). In next request will need to sent **salt** to server. The **salt** must be different for all connections in Pool and I think Connection must store **salt** inself.

So, my implementation is...
Spring Beans XML:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                                   type="client"
                                   host="localhost"
                                   port="12345"
                                   interceptor-factory-chain="customInterceptorFactory"
                                   mapper="mapper" />

    <bean id="customInterceptorFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <bean class="ru.example.gateway.StatefulTcpConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="cachedClient" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="client" />
        <constructor-arg value="5" />
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="clientRequestChannel"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="clientCrLf"
                                connection-factory="cachedClient"
                                request-channel="clientRequestChannel"/>

    <int:converter ref="byteArrayToStringConverter" />
    <bean id="byteArrayToStringConverter" class="ru.example.gateway.ByteArrayToStringConverter">
        <property name="charset" value="windows-1251" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mapper" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper">
        <property name="charset" value="windows-1251" />
    </bean>
```

TCP connection interceptor:

```
package ru.example.gateway;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionSupport;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

@Slf4j
@Getter
public class StatefulTcpConnection extends TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport {

    private volatile String nextSalt = "";
    private final AtomicBoolean initialized = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public StatefulTcpConnection() {
    }

    public StatefulTcpConnection(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        super(applicationEventPublisher);
    }

    @Override
    public void send(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        if (!initialized.get()) {
            throw new Exception("Connection not initialized");
        }
        Message<?> newMessage = message;
        Object payload = message.getPayload();
        log.debug("Send Payload({})", payload.getClass());
        if (payload instanceof String) {
            new GenericMessage<String>((String) payload + ";Salt=" + nextSalt + ";", message.getHeaders());
        }
        super.send(newMessage);
    }

    /**
     * Invoke initialize after connection wrapped in ConnectionFactory4Interceptors
     * @see org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory#initializeConnection(TcpConnectionSupport, Socket)
     * @param serializer
     */
    @Override
    public void setSerializer(Serializer<?> serializer) {
        super.setSerializer(serializer);
        try {
            initialize();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Connection couldn't initialize", e);
        }
    }

    private void initialize() throws Exception {
        GenericMessage<String> loginMessage = new GenericMessage<>("Login");
        super.send(loginMessage);
        log.debug("Waiting initializing response");
        latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMessage(Message<?> message) {
        Object messagePayload = message.getPayload();
        log.debug("onMessage Payload({})", messagePayload.getClass());
        messagePayload = new String((byte[]) messagePayload);
        if (messagePayload instanceof String) {
            String payload = (String) messagePayload,
                salt;
            int saltStart = payload.indexOf(";Salt=");
            if (saltStart >= 0) {
                int saltEnd = payload.indexOf(";", saltStart + 1);
                if (saltEnd >= 0) {
                    salt = payload.substring(saltStart + 6, saltEnd);
                } else {
                    salt = payload.substring(saltStart + 6);
                }
                nextSalt = salt;
            }
            if (!initialized.get()) {
                initialized.set(true);
                latch.countDown();
                log.debug("Initializing complete.");
            }
        }
        return super.onMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public String getConnectionId() {
        return "Stateful:" + super.getConnectionId();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getConnectionId();
    }

}
```

Gateway:

```
package ru.example.gateway;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;

@MessagingGateway(name = "clientOutGateway",
    defaultRequestChannel = "clientRequestChannel"
)
public interface StringGateway {

    String send(String message);

}
```

And service for Spring MVC:

```
package ru.example.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import ru.example.gateway.StringGateway;
import ru.example.service.MessageService;

@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private StringGateway clientGateway;

    public String getMessage(String code) {
        return clientGateway.send(code);
    }

}
```

I have some errors. In first request from **MessageServiceImpl** I gained response for "authentication request" and needed response lost, or throw Exception, or error message in log:

```
ERROR org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Cannot correlate response - no pending reply for Cached:Stateful:localhost:12345:56060:6993fc83-7e69-4f18-9300-8553e6d74a4f
```

Are someone have solution for Stateful Connection?

Thanks!
p.s.: sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no stateful connection management provided by the framework. You could write a wrapper for the connection factory that stores the connection in a `ThreadLocal` but you would need some mechanism to clean up (and release it) when you are done with the connection.

If it's just a simple handshake you might be able to use connection interceptors; there's a test case (see [HelloWorldInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection)) but it's a bit complicated.

I would think a custom connection factory wrapper would be simpler.

Comment: In my example, state(field nextSalt) of every connection works good. I have problems with sending authorization request and collerate response after authorization.